# gdb shows wrong addresses while zeroing a buffer

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, x86-64, nasm

My objective is to initialize a buffer in assembly. I use NASM on a 64bit-linux and gdb for debugging. The relevant assembler is the following (I copy-pasted from gdb's TUI mode, so you can see the line numbers):

```
│   4           section .data 
│   5            
│   6           length dd 4096       
│   7           format db "%20ld",10,0         
│   8         
│   9           section .bss 
│   10
│   11          buffer resd 4096

│   83          init_buffer: 
│   84            ;we will use r8 for our counter 
│   85            ;and r9 for the buffer base address 
│   86            xor r8,r8
│   87            lea r9, [buffer]
│   88            mov r10d, DWORD 0xDADADA; not 0 to make debugging easier
│   89            mov eax, [length]   
│   90            movsxd rax, eax
│   91          .init_buffer_loop:
│   92            mov [r9 + r8*4], r10d
│   93            inc r8 
│   94            cmp r8, rax 
│   95            jb .init_buffer_loop
│   96            ret
```

I use the following command to build the program (I use printf at another moment):

```
nasm -F dwarf -f elf64 myProgram.asm && gcc -g myProgram.o
```

While debugging another problem (I use `gdb -tui a.out`), I realised that the value in r9 and the address of `buffer` are different:

```
(gdb) b    87
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4011a8: file myProgram.asm, line 87.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /path/to/my/program

Breakpoint 1, init_buffer () at myProgram.asm:87
(gdb) p    &buffer
$1 = (char **) 0x7ffff7fa0250 <buffer>
(gdb) n
(gdb) i    r r9
r9             0x405034            4214836
(gdb) n
init_buffer.init_buffer_loop () at myProgram.asm:92
;//some next instructions are missing here, we are at line 94 now:
(gdb) x    /1xd 4214836
0x405034 <buffer>:    14342874
(gdb) x    /4x 4214836
0x405034 <buffer>:    0x00dadada    0x00000000    0x00000000    0x00000000
(gdb) p    (int[4])buffer
$3 = {0, 0, 0, 0}
```

Is there a mistake in the assembly code? Or am I debugging it wrong? I asked some programmers, who could not explain it to me, but they hadn't much experience with gdb-ing assembly...

Comment: You likely have multiple symbols named `buffer`.

Comment: `cat myProgram.asm | grep ^\s+buffer` gives only one result

Comment: @Jester: Or glibc has some internal `static int buffer[]` in some source file; generic names like `buf` clashing with glibc debug symbols / global vars is a common problem for questions like this.

Comment: Yes, I meant "you" in the general sense. Of course there can't be multiple symbols with the same name in the same file.

Comment: Forgot that there was already a Q&A that explained this when I commented earlier, could have saved you the trouble of writing up your own answer. >.<  For some reason this is the 2nd or 3rd time this issue has come up in the last week on SO.

Comment: Thanks for linking and closing, if you don't know the real reason for this behavior, it is hard to search for this problem. I spend some time to find a Q&A here before asking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments indicated, there is another variable called `buffer` in another source file of glibc. Changing the variable name to `puffer` gives the expected results.
Furthermore, the following line should have made me skeptical:

```
$1 = (char **) 0x7ffff7fa0250 <buffer>
```

gdb did not interfered types in my assembler code, but it knew that I put `char **`s in my buffer.